# What Method.isBridge used for?

Tags: java, api, reflection

During navigation of the `java.lang.reflect.Method` class I came across the method `isBridge`. Its Javadoc says that it returns true only if the Java spec declares the method as true.

Please help me understand what this is used for! Can a custom class declare its method as a bridge if required?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A bridge method may be created by the compiler when extending a parameterized type whose methods have parameterized arguments.

You can find in this class [BridgeMethodResolver](https://fisheye.springsource.org/browse/spring-framework/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/BridgeMethodResolver.java?r=02a4473c62d8240837bec297f0a1f3cb67ef8a7b) a way to get the actual Method referred by a 'bridge method'.

See [Create Frame, Synchronize, Transfer Control](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.12.4.5):

As an example of such a situation, consider the declarations:

```
class C<T> { abstract T id(T x); }
class D extends C<String> { String id(String x) { return x; } }
```

Now, given an invocation

```
C c = new D();
c.id(new Object()); // fails with a ClassCastException
```

The erasure of the actual method being invoked, `D.id(String)` differs in its signature from that of the compile-time method declaration, `C.id(Object)`. The former takes an argument of type String while the latter takes an argument of type Object. The invocation fails with a ClassCastException before the body of the method is executed.

Such situations can only arise if the program gives rise to an unchecked warning ([§5.1.9](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#190772)).

Implementations can enforce these semantics by creating bridge methods. In the above example, the following bridge method would be created in class D:

```
Object id(Object x) { return id((String) x); }
```

This is the method that would actually be invoked by the Java virtual machine in response to the call `c.id(new Object())` shown above, and it will execute the cast and fail, as required.

See also **[Bridge](http://books.google.com/books?id=zaoK0%5A2STlkC&pg=PA50&lpg=PA50&dq=java+bridge+%22covariant+return+types%22&source=web&ots=6WoofeXYFM&sig=8bS5Y0sw%5ApBu%5ACuf1EkIR_L4Ddo&hl=en&sa=X&oi=book_result&resnum=4&ct=result#PPA48,M1)**:

as mentioned in the comment, bridge methods are also needed for **covariant overriding**:

- In Java 1.4, and earlier, one method can override another if the signatures match 
  exactly.
- In Java 5, a method can override another if the arguments match exactly *but the return type* of the overriding method, if it is a *subtype* of the return type of the other method.

Typically, a method `Object clone()` can be overridden by a `MyObject clone()`, but a bridge method will be generated by the compiler:

```
public bridge Object MyObject.clone();
```

Comment: Even without generics, bridge methods are necessary for covariant return types.

Comment: @BrunoJCM good catch. I have restore the link (the class has been moved from project `org.springframework.core` to project `spring-framework`: https://fisheye.springsource.org/browse/spring-framework/org.springframework.core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/BridgeMethodResolver.java#rdc41daa3db350ef9a4b14ef1d750d79cb22cf431)

Comment: A third use of bridge methods is the alteration of a methods visibility to public if the class was declared with package private visibility.

Answer (score 3):

The example shown there (quoted from the JLS) makes it sound like bridge methods are only used in situations where raw types are used. Since this is not the case, I thought I'd pipe in with an example where bridge methods are used for totally type-correct generic code.

Consider the following interface and function:

```
public static interface Function<A,R> {
    public R apply (A arg);
}
public static <A, R> R applyFunc (Function<A,R> func, A arg) {
    return func.apply(arg);
}
```

If you use this code in the following way, a bridge method is used:

```
Function<String, String> lower = new Function<String, String>() {
    public String apply (String arg) {
        return arg.toLowerCase();
    }
};
applyFunc(lower, "Hello");
```

After erasure, the `Function` interface contains the method `apply(Object)Object` (which you can confirm by decompiling the bytecode). Naturally, if you look at the decompiled code for `applyFunc` you'll see that it contains a call to `apply(Object)Object`. `Object` is the upper bound of its type variables, so no other signature would make sense.

So when an anonymous class is created with the method `apply(String)String`, it doesn't actually implement the `Function` interface unless a bridge method is created. The bridge method allows all generically typed code to make use of that `Function` implementation.

Interestingly, only if the class implemented some *other* interface with the signature `apply(String)String` and only if the method was called via a reference of that interface type would the compiler ever emit a call with that signature.

Even if I have the following code:

```
Function<String, String> lower = ...;
lower.apply("Hello");
```

The compiler still emits a call to `apply(Object)Object`.

There is actually one other way to get the compiler to call `apply(String)String`, but it takes advantage of the magical type assigned to an anonymous class creation expression which cannot otherwise be written down:

```
new Function<String, String>() {
    public String apply (String arg) {
        return arg.toLowerCase();
    }
}.apply("Hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

Another case I stumbled across has nothing to do with generics:

```
protected abstract class Super {
    public void m() {}
}
public class Sub extends Super {}
assert Sub.class.getMethod("m").isBridge();
```