# Java Reflection getDeclaredMethods() returns two versions of generic overridden methods

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I need to use the Reflection API to get exact information on the method parameters of the methods in a class.
Consider the following minimal example:

```java
public class A<T> {
  void test(T t, List<String> l) {}
}

public class B extends A<Integer> {
  @Override
  void test(Bar t, List<String> l) {}
}

public class Main{
  public static void main() {
    Method[] methods = B.class.getDeclaredMethods();
    for (Method m : methodsB) {
      System.out.println(m);
      System.out.println(m.getGenericParameterTypes()[1] instanceof ParameterizedType)
    }
  }
}
```

This will result in

```
void B.test(java.lang.Integer,java.util.List)
true
void B.test(java.lang.Object,java.util.List)
false
```

My question is:

1. why does `getDeclaredMethods()` output *two* methods instead of one? If `test` doesn't have a generic parameter or if it would be a new method of `B` (not overridden), `getDeclaredMethods()` will output only one methods, as expected.
2. what would be a realiable and general way to filter out the "wrong" methods, which don't include generic type information?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html, [What Method.isBridge used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/289731)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Pshemo pointed out, the second, less specific method is a **Bridge Method** (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html) which is used as a means of type erasure.

Bridge methods can be identified using `method.isBridge()`.